# boost.asio's socket's receive/send functions are bad?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

> Data may be read from or written to a
>   connected TCP socket using the
>   receive(), async_receive(), send()  or
>   async_send()  member functions.
>   However, as these could result in
>   short writes or reads, an application
>   will typically use the following
>   operations instead: read(),
>   async_read(), write() and
>   async_write().

I don't really understand that remark as read(), async_read(), write() and async_write() can also end up in short writes or reads, right?
Why are those functions not the same?
Should I use them at all?
Can someone clarify that remark for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *read*, *async_read*, *write*, and *async_write* are **composed** functions that call the class functions multiple times until the requested number of bytes is transmitted. They are included by the library as a convenience. Otherwise, every developer would need to implement the same logic.

The class functions wrap the underlying OS functions directly, which basically state in the documentation: these functions may return before all of the bytes are transmitted.

In most cases, you should use the free (composed) functions to transmit data.

Comment: Why was it designed this way? In which case you don't need to receive all the bytes that were requested?
Why doesn't the socket object include the read/write/async_read/async_write? You are passing a socket anyway.

Comment: I don't know why, but you can probably find the answer in the "Networking Library Proposal for TR2." http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2054.pdf

Comment: Regarding the previously linked document, look at page 8.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you have to understand the word "asynchronous", it simply means "need not to wait". 
After asynchronous actions are invoked, the following action will execute **without waiting for** the asynchronous action return. While synchronous **have to wait** until previous synchronous actions return.
The two following samples from Boost.Asio would make sense:
[A synchronous TCP daytime server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime2.html)

(Oops! not enough reputation, the second sample is easy to find though, called "An asynchronous TCP daytime server")

Comment: How is this related to my question?

Comment: sorry.... i assume the first paragraph in your question was a quote... so i ingore them.....